# How to Run Compose UI tests multiple times in a row locally?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, uitest, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I have a bunch of UI tests in the codebase with which I am currently working that are marked as `@FlakyTest`. Usually the fail on the CI but very rarely they also fail locally.

I am looking for a way to run one single test multiple times in a row to see how often it fails. Ideally it should be an annotation like `@Repeat(n times)`.

Note that the UI tests are testing `Composable` components so I can't use Espresso.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Barista library or use a different test runner.
https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista

One of these test runners is Marathon
https://github.com/MarathonLabs/marathon